# map function with unit type output

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
type ('a, 'b) t =
  | Leaf of 'b
  | Node of 'a * ('a, 'b) t* ('a, 'b) t
```

I want to implement a `map f g t` function with signature: `val map: (('a -> unit) * ('b -> unit)) -> ('a,'b) t -> unit`

where:

- `f` to all node data
- `g` to all leaf data

and it should iterate via preorder traversal (root-left-right)

This is what I have tried:

```
let rec map f g t = 
  match t with
  | Leaf w  -> Leaf (g w)
  | Node (v, l, r) -> Node (f v, map f g l, map f g r)
```

But I don't know how to get that signature matched, any ideas?

Comment: just declare it as `let rec map (f, g) t = ...` and it'll fit the signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `f` and `g` to each have a return type of `unit`, then this isn't really `map` at all. It's more of an `iter` function, and you might write it more like:

```
let rec iter f g =
  function
  | Leaf v -> let () = g v in ()
  | Node (v, l, r) ->
    let () = f v in
    let () = iter f g l in
    iter f g r
```

This function has the following type because we have provided enough information to the compiler to infer that `f` and `g` return `unit`.

```
('a -> unit) -> ('b -> unit) -> ('a, 'b) t -> unit
```

Note that this also guarantees that the recursive call on the node value will occur first, followed by the recursive call on the left branch, followed by the recursive call on the right branch; whereas evaluation order in `Node (f v, map f g l, map f g r)` is not specified and may change between implementations.

As noted in comments, a few explicit type annotations remove the need to bind to `unit` to let the type inferencing work properly.

```
# let rec iter (f : 'a -> unit) (g : 'b -> unit) t =
    match t with
    | Leaf v -> g v
    | Node (v, l, r) ->
      f v;
      iter f g l;
      iter f g r;;
val iter : ('a -> unit) -> ('b -> unit) -> ('a, 'b) t -> unit = <fun>
```

Comment: Not only the order of evaluation is unspecified, so one shouldn't rely on it, but AFAIK it's currently right-to-left, so it wouldn't even work right now.

Comment: Why redundant `let` and not just semicolons? To enforce the unit type? Wouldn't a type annotation be more adequate?

Comment: That would work too.

Comment: Semi-colons would ignore a result of any type, which would lead to a warning I guess during compilation